# How to implement the below SQL query in RetrieveMultiple Plug-in on contact entity in CRM 2013

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I would like to implement the below SQL query in `RetriveMultiple` plug-in on `contact` entity.

```
SELECT contactid, restricted, sensitive, fullname
FROM contact
JOIN RelationsTeam ON contactid = RelationsTeamId
WHERE membersystemuserid = 'XXXXX'
UNION
SELECT contactid, restricted, sensitive, fullname
FROM contact
WHERE restricted = 1
```

Relations are like this: 1-N from `contact` to `RelationsTeam` and N-1 from `RelationsTeam` to `SystemUser` entities.

The requirement is: I need to get all the contacts who are flagged as Restricted when the logged in user is having restricted access privileges or belongs to relations team of contact.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will stronly suggest you to follow this article, if you are not using early bound it can be a little more complex.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334415.aspx

Also can't you join the 2 conditions with an or?

```
SELECT contactid, restricted, sensitive, fullname
FROM contact
JOIN RelationsTeam ON contactid = RelationsTeamId
WHERE membersystemuserid = 'XXXXX' OR restricted = 1
```

Comment: Hi Draiden I would like to elaborate on my question above. The membersystemuserid is not the attibute of contact.

Comment: Yes Sorry but you can use an alias, I will give you an example of a linq query made that way (to translate queries from sql i suggest you to go with linq :))

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to implement your query like this:

```
var queryRes = from d in xrmService.ContactSet
               join c in xrmService.RelationsTeamSet 
               on d.contactid equals c.RelationsTeamId                            
               where d.membersystemuserid = 'XXXXX' or c.restricted = 1
                                     select new
                                     {
                                        // list of attributes;
                                     }
```

now the query is not working, is just to give you an idea on how you can replicate that sql query in a plugin.